# fs.writeFile has no errors, but fails to write file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am using node.js, trying to save a file, no errors are thrown, yes the image won't save. This is how I am saving the file:

```
var url = 'captures/' + getFileName() + '.png';

    fs.writeFile(url, base64, 'base64', function(err) {

        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        }
    });
```

With a helper to make the file names for me:

```
function getFileName(){
    var d = new Date()
    return d.getMonth()+'-'+d.getDate()+'-'+d.getYear()+'-'+d.getHours()+'-'+d.getMinutes()+d.getSeconds();
}
```

Anyone had trouble with this?

Comment: Can you throw in some logs. Before the fs.writeFile, log the url and base64, then inside the function, log the same and the error. That may help. Thanks

Comment: Sure, I tried logging all parts. They all log fine.

Comment: Even does the same when I add the absolute URL...

Comment: try this: `fs.writeFile(url, base64, {encoding:'base64'}, function(err) {//...})`

Comment: Just to confirm, so are using a path relative to the current working directory, not relative to the script. Are you sure you are looking in the right place?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any luck on resolving this? :/

Comment: Same issue, no solution so far?

Comment: In my case, I was passing in an undefined variable as the file-location to write to. I guess this makes the error happen before the callback even gets called and that is why my console.log (within the callback) never fired.

Answer (score 48):

the problem is because this call is async and probably is loosing the context right after, I was able to fix it on my end by using `fs.writeFileSync` which does it synchronously. hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Add a `console.log('captures/' + getFileName())` just to make sure your file name is correct.  When I had this problem it turned out that I had a problem with the file path/name and node just wasn't throwing me an error to explain.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write your file asynchronously, try using `fs/promises` instead of `fs`.

```js
const { writeFile } = require("fs/promises");

(async () => {
    await writeFile('myFile.txt', 'my content', (err) => {});
})();
```

`writeFile` from `fs` is void. It will execute asynchronously but not in the async-await meaning. `writeFile` from `fs/promises` returns a Promise so async-await will work as expected.

Learn more here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#callback-example

Answer (score 2):

For Typescript version,
Just sharing my experience here, In my use case had a JSON file where I used to store some temporary data read it and make some changes and update it and store that updated data to same JSON file will be used for next cycle.
`fs.writeFile` was not throwing any error at same time it was not updating my JSON file where as JS version worked well, Then I realized that typescript made these changes in my root or src directory. Created another JSON file there.

Answer (score -2):

There might be a permission issue.

go inside the directory that you are saving your files and then

`sudo chmod 777 .`